# How to label content set using triggers/( etc) when bind value null or empty in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, label

I want to bind label content dynamically at run time. When the binding property null or empty I want to show bind value(name) as content. I have try as below but it not works:
when binding property has a value it works fine.
XAML code as follows.

```
<Label Content="{DynamicResource name}">
    <Label.Style>
        <Style>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding name}" Value="{x:NULL}">
                    <Setter Property="Label.Content" Value="name" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Label.Style>
</Label>
```

Help me. Thanks!

Comment: can you show where you defined your name property

Comment: how you added dynamic resource show some more code

Comment: name is a key and it has value in a database table.I assign key and value to dictionry type list. That dictionry list add to Resources of the window.

Comment: can you show that code

Comment: edit ur quesion and write code their

Comment: Is `TargetNullValue` not an option? - Nevermind just saw kmatyaszek's added answer

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `DataTrigger` you can use `TargetNullValue` property ([msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingbase.targetnullvalue.aspx)).

> Gets or sets the value that is used in the target when the value of
>   the source is null.

Example:

```
<Label Content="{Binding LabelContent, TargetNullValue=LabelContent}" />
```

Solution in code-behind:

You don't have to write trigger. You can check value before adding it to `Resources`:

```
...
foreach (var item in resourceList)
{
    if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Value))   
        window.Resources.Add(item.Key, item.Value);
    else
        window.Resources.Add(item.Key, item.Key);
}
...
```

Comment: @user2632652 check my answer again :)